# python 3 path.exists() or os.path.exists(path) or open(path) is very slow if the path is on mountpoint that does not exist

Tags: python-3.x, performance, io

I noticed this weird behavior where checking if paths existed with those paths being in /media mount points that are not mounted (that is: a external removable disc that is not connected) is exponentially slower than checking on local disc paths.

Is this a known bug? And how can i avoid it?

Should i just glob the mount points in '/media' and if a path starts in '/media' but isn't in the glob, skip it?

Is there a way to make this idea portable or is it hopeless to try?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the 'slowness' is that i had fstab file where i automounted the external drive with a too long timeout.

Specifically i had on the options `nofail,noatime,x-systemd-automount,x-systemd.device-timeout=1s`

Omitting the option is even more disastrous btw, the default timeout is 90 seconds or something.

I ended up removing the automount and using '1ms' instead of '1s' for the timeout.

Removing the automount is not actually necessary, i think, and i might add it back, because it allows mount to happen even if you don't start gnome, and before autostart gnome programs although it conflicts/duplicates mountpoints with the gnome 'autostart' from autofs and can only be removed with the 'Disks' program in gnome, and requires using `x-gvfs-hide` to hide the ugly duplicated mountpoint.